# aws cli create-snapshot fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, volume, snapshot

Trying to create snapshot of ebs volume.  I have the below command in aws cli windows

```
aws --profile ade --region us-east-1 ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol- 
012709ebb854c5fdd --description 'c-drive of i-00ca23fae0887e018' --tags- 
specifications 'ResourceType=snapshot,Tags=[{Key=Product,Value=csf}, 
{Key=Service,Value=datamigration},{Key=Name,Value=cdrive-dms}, 
{Key=Team,Value=DMS},{Key=Owner,Value=alexwolff}]'
```

I get response:

> Uknown options: --tag-specifications, ResourceType=snapshot,Tags[{Key=Product,Value=csf},{Key=Service,Value=datamigration},{Key=Name,Value=cdrive-dms},{Key=Team,Value=DMS},{Key=Owner,Value=alexwolff}]

It's got to be a simple syntax mistake...can anybody spot it?  I've tried switching single quotes to double quotes and vice-versa.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy & paste the command and error message, or retype them? The command shows `--tags-specifications` while the error shows `--tag-specifications`, together with a spelling error. Please provide the exact values rather than re-typing them.

Comment: Are you running this command on Windows, MacOS or Linux? If Windows, you need to use double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that ended up working for me was:

```
aws --profile ade --region us-east-1 ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol- 
012709ebb854c5fdd --description "c-drive of i-00ca23fae0887e018" --tag-specification 
'ResourceType=snapshot,Tags=[{Key=Product,Value=csf},{Key=Service,Value=datamigration}, 
{Key=Name,Value=cdrive-dms},{Key=Team,Value=DMS},{Key=Owner,Value=alexwolff}]'
```

> tag-specification